# Adding a Property to an existing class

Tags: c#, properties

I have a private class that I'm using to implement certain properties. As such, I don't have the ability to modify the actual private class, and don't want to use inheritance to create my own class in place of it. Is there a way where I can add properties to that private class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can access the data in the class that you need, and can live with methods instead of properties, look into [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), introduced in C# 3.0. From that article, here's an extension method added to the (sealed, non-modifiable) String class:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
   public static int WordCount(this String str)
   {
       return str.Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', '?' }, 
                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
   }
}
```

From [the horse's mouth](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/05/why-no-extension-properties.aspx), extension *properties* are a possibility in a future version of C#.

This won't help you if you need to access private fields or methods. In that case, you might look into reflection, but I'd advise staying away from that unless it's really necessary - it can get messy sometimes.

Comment: strictly speaking, C# 3.0 (not .NET 3.0), since you can use extension methods against *any* version of .NET if you simply define the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose of the properties is for data-binding, then you can add runtime properties to types *outside your control* using `TypeDescriptionProvider`, which is a factory for an `ICustomTypeDescriptor`. You would then chain the original provider and create a custom `PropertyDescriptor` that obtained the additional data.

This is reasonably easy for read-only extra properties that are calculated based on the *existing* properties (and by "reasonably easy" I mean "only slightly insane"), but for read-write properties (or properties that are independent to the existing members) it is very hard, as you need to figure out **where to put those values** (in a way that still gets garbage collected etc). Non-trivial.