# Add properties to existing class

Tags: c#

I have an existing class and I want to add 2 properties to it, [not methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810488/adding-a-property-to-an-existing-class/3810505#3810505). Is this possible? If not possible, how can I inherit it and have the same class name?

Comment: Ummm... Excuse my stupid question but... What stops you from editing that class directly ?

Comment: Class is part of System.Web.Mvc. Cannot touch it.

Comment: inheritance then. not possible to do partial classes in different assemblies

Comment: Which class are you talking about? Is it a **partial** class by any chance??

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
public int Property1 { get; set; }
public int Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
 public int Property3 { get; set; }
 public int Property4 { get; set; }
}
```

Not possible to inherit using the same name, but :

File1.cs

```
public partial class MyBaseClass
{
   public int Property1 { get; set; }
   public int Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

File2. cs

```
public partial class MyBaseClass
{
   public int Property3 { get; set; }
   public int Property4 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as extension properties, and you can't inherit the class and use the same class name, unless you use a different namespace, which is probably not what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Why not download the source([MVC3](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781)) and edit the class directly?